# Trying to get location with cell tower but still returns null

Tags: android, gps

What I am trying to do is to get location from user. First it tries to get location through GPS and checks whether location is available. If not then it it tries to get through Network tower. When GPS is turned on it is working fine. But when I turn off GPS it's not getting location using network provider

```
 manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = manager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    Log.i("ITEMSET best", provider);


    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    Log.i("ITEMSET provider", provider);

    location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    Log.i("ITEMSET netLoc", location + "");
    if(location==null) {
        provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        Log.i("ITEMSET netLoc", location + "qqq");
    }



    Log.i("ITEMSET current", provider);
    Log.i("ITEMSET location", location  + "");
```

[image: Logcat]

Location was initially null because GPS wasn't turned on. But then changed provider to network provider. But location still null

Comment: have you given fine location permission?

Comment: Yes I've given both fine location and coarse location permissions.

Comment: may be you haven't request for location update , that's why its giving issue

Comment: if (isNetworkEnabled) {
           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 100, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }

Comment: I requested locationupdate in onresume block

Comment: @IbrokhimjonSaydakhmatov may be its taking time to get the location? Just to test once can u restart your device and test once with only network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Whether Network is Enabled or not

```
 isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

then:

```
     if (isNetworkEnabled) {
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000,10, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();


                    }
                }
```

Comment: That's the case. Seems like provider is not enabled

Answer (score 1):

You should use `GoogleApiClient` to get your location. Please visit [this post](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/)